# Springboot 2.1.9.RELEASE - Persist Entities with Parent Child relationship using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, json, jpa

I have a one to many relation between `Employee` and `Address` tables in mysql. I was hoping that when I persist the parent with children data, the parent gets created first and its `parent_id` is used in the child table automatically. I am getting the following error.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated**:

Parent code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Column(length = 6)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    private long id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dob;
    
    @Column(name="email_address")
    private String emailAddress;
    
    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;


    @Column(name="last_name")
    private String lastName;
    
    @Column(name="user_id")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="email_verified")
    private String emailVerification;
   
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, mappedBy = "employee", orphanRemoval = true, 
   cascade = 
    CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Address> addresses = null;

    public Employee() {
    }

    public Employee(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

Child:

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "address")
   public class Address implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(length = 6)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)     
    private long id;

    @Basic
    private String address1;

    @Basic
    private String address2;


    @Basic
    private String city;

    @Basic
    private String zip;

    
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "emp_id")
    private String empId;   

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", nullable = false, updatable=false, insertable=false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Employee employee;
    
    @Basic
    private int state_id;

    public Address() {
    }

    public Address(long id) {
        this.id = id;       
    }

    public long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
```

Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin (origins = "*" )
@PostMapping("/employee")
public Employee createEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
    return employeeRepository.save(employee);
}
```

JSON INPUT:

```
{
  "dob": "2001-11-12",
  "emailAddress": "aaa@gmail.com",
  "firstName": "John",
  "gender": "M",
  "lastName": "Wilson",
  "userName": "jon",
  "password": "pass",
  "emailVerification": null,
  "addresses": [
    {
      "address1": "123 My Street",
      "address2": null,
      "city": "MyCity1",
      "zip": "11111",
      "stateId": 1
    },
    {
      "address1": "567 My Street",
      "address2": null,
      "city": "MyCity2",
      "zip": "22222",
      "stateId": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

ERROR

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        address
        (address1, address2, city, emp_id, state_id, zip) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2021-04-28 22:17:19.067 RACE 25508 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [567 My Street]
2021-04-28 22:17:19.067 TRACE 25508 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2021-04-28 22:17:19.067 TRACE 25508 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [3] as [VARCHAR] - [MyCity2]
2021-04-28 22:17:19.067 TRACE 25508 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [4] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
2021-04-28 22:17:19.067 TRACE 25508 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [5] as [INTEGER] - [1]
2021-04-28 22:17:19.067 TRACE 25508 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [6] as [VARCHAR] - [22222]
2021-04-28 22:17:19.071  WARN 25508 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1048, SQLState: 23000
2021-04-28 22:17:19.071 ERROR 25508 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'emp_id' cannot be null
2021-04-28 22:17:19.094  WARN 25508 --- [nio-9090-exec-2] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null];
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to go through all the addresses and set the `employee` property manually. You should do it manually because the JSON deserialization will not touch that field, even without the `@JsonIgnore` annotation. But that is only the surface of the problems.

You are setting `updatable=false, insertable=false` on the `employee` property. There is another property, the `String empId`, that maps to the same column, indicating that you want to manage the relationship manually. The type of the column/property should be the same as the PK/id of the related entity, so `long`! And, given that the JSON does not contain the `empId` either, you still need to set it by hand; but you do *NOT* know it at the time of the creation! If you remove the `Address.empId` property *AND* the `updatable=false, insertable=false` *AND* set the `employee` manually, it should work.

If you want Jackson to do that for you, you can use `@JsonManagedReference` on the `Employee.addresses` property and `@JsonBackReference` on the `Address.employee`, *in addition to the tasks discussed in the previous paragraph* (remove `updatable=false, insertable=false` and the `String empId` property) *AND* removing the `@JsonIgnore` of course. See a detailed description [here](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-managed-reference.html):

```java
@JsonManagedReference
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Address.class, mappedBy = "employee", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Address> addresses = null;

@JsonBackReference
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "emp_id", nullable = false)
private Employee employee;
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I am against mixing JPA & Jackson annotations. It is convenient indeed because you do not need a separate DTO class, you do not need mapping logic and you do not need to worry for the CPU/memory needed to do the transformation Entity ↔ DTO. On the other hand, data transfer and data persistence are *two entirely different concerns*, so SOLID goes down the drain. And there is the chance of sending fields that are not supposed to be seen by the client (e.g. the password or email of a `User` entity).